# What does Zayin Ayin VeNun mean in the Ashkenazi Yotzer for Shabbos Rosh Chodesh?

Tags: shabbat, song-poetry, rosh-chodesh-new-month, nusach-ashkenaz, yotzrot

In the Ashkenazi Yotzer for Shabbos Rosh Chodesh, the the Paytan (Rabbeinu Binyomin ben Zerach) writes in the "nun" verse "וזיי''ן עיי''ן ןנו''ן פשוטה מכריעות לכלנה" What does this mean? See [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Lp1EAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP449&lpg=PP449&dq=%D7%95%D7%96%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F+%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F+%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9F&source=bl&ots=VBCOXv6Jmb&sig=zSVEwR_ZbcziKrRpz2zgV626RoA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU17rOxtTUAhXDAMAKHZpqBCEQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: The commentary in your link says that if you arrange the letters out then אבגדהו needs ז to be added to get 28 which is the length of a solar cycle. So too יכלמנס needs ע to get to 280 which is the length of 10 solar cycles. Etc. I'm not sure why this is so significant that a poem would reference it.